# How can I find the number of pending incoming UDP packets? (Networking Related)

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, udp

How to find the number of pending packets (not bytes) to receive in the input buffer of a bound UDP socket, from a C program? It can be a Linux specific interface.

The closes I found is the `SIOCINQ` option for `ioctl()`, but it returns the number of bytes of the next packet, not the number of total packets.

Comment: Usually you fetch them. I'm not sure the POSIX networking API lets you check the number of "packets". As far as the network stack is concerned, packets don't exist, they're the responsibility of the physical transport layer. The POSIX stack is concerned with *datagrams* which are a higher-level abstraction built on the actual packets. A single datagram could be sent as multiple packets, etc.

Comment: By packet I mean: each network level has its own packet type. UDP packet, specifically, is a datagram.

Comment: Why do you need to know how many udp datagrams are in the receive queue?  You could read the socket in non blocking mode until it generates `EWOULDBLOCK`, but then they would no longer be in the receive queue.

Comment: Please post your question on https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @pat To conform with a preexisting interface without having to reimplement it in userspace.

Comment: Does that interface need to know the actual number or is it sufficient to say 0 when there are 0 datagrams queued, and 1 when there are 1 or more?  I.e. what does the user of the interface do with the value?

Comment: The interface should provide the actual number of packets, but I don't know if the users actually need that information.

Comment: @Dave123 Did you consult https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic first? It is not particularly on topic there, this is clearly a programming question.

Comment: What I mean is "packet" and "datagram" are often confused but are actually two different things. Short of opening a raw socket and listening at the transport level (e.g. `tcpdump` or Wireshark) all you can see is the final, defragmented datagrams. You also need to drain the queue to count what's in it.The normal indications are receive buffer empty, receive buffer has data, and receive buffer full.

Comment: I believe, there is no such way in Linux. The use case is rather unusual, out of curiosity, why is this of interest to you?

Comment: @lvella There is no portable (or even nonstandard) way to get the number of pending datagrams in a socket's receive queue. If you absolutely need the actual number of pending datagrams, you will likely have to read the datagrams in the background into your own queue, and then you can return (the number of) entries from that queue as needed.

Comment: ...by which time, another X datagrams have arrived.   This is a bad requirement that should be designed away if possible:(